# Create gmail, facebook and twitter account through API?

Tags: api, facebook, twitter, gmail

Is it possible to create gmail, facebook and twitter account through API?

Comment: Can we create  Facebook and Twitter account through api now?Its been a long since this question was asked and many changes has been done since then.SO need to reconfirm that?Do Facebook Graph api supports this?What abt Twitter?

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: No.

Comment: No, because it would make it too easy to spam accounts.

Comment: @ajsie: I would like to think that the main reason is to prevent the  mass spam-bots registration.

Comment: Set up an "API" to a Crowdsource provider. :|

Comment: It's possible with FB

Comment: @Andrey Botalov: any reference? PS: keep in mind we're talking about real accounts, not testing ones

Comment: @Andrey Botalov: and OP eventually had asked about real accounts

Comment: @zerkms there's no either "real" or "test" in question so I assumed it doesn't matter. OP asks about just accounts

Comment: @Andrey Botalov: I'm sure with your experience you may extrapolate in this case. Indeed, programming is a precise science, but this question isn't about testing, it's about spam-alike activity :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well for Google Apps you can sync a user directory (via LDAP) using [Google Apps Directory Sync](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106368).  This will provision, modify and de-provision any number of accounts without CAPTCHA verification.  You will be billed for each one you create and they will all be in a domain you must own so there are practical limits for abuse, but this scales out to tens of thousands of accounts.  There is no method to do this for Twitter and Facebook but things like this are a large part of the draw (for companies) of services like Yammer and App.net.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for a fixed premier or education domain you can create accounts programmatically using the google provision api.