# Create Email account from type existing Account Services

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-account

I have gone through ***SampleSyncAdapter*** sample project provided by Android doc, but as I understand, there we need to add an account of custom Account service.
*But my need is to create an email account from existing account services on device.*

---

***To be more clear about my question, I am giving an example***

Here are the Account services available on my Device
[image]

and I guess 'Google' and 'Email' account services are available on each Android device.

Now I want to configure an 'Email' account, so I must follow these below steps:

***Step 1:*** Enter existing email id and password

***Step 2: [a]*** General Settings
            Attributes : - (Account name, Real Name, Email Address)

***Step 2: [b]*** Incoming server
            Attributes : - (POP or IMAP mail server, Server Address, user name, password)

***Step 2: [c]*** Outgoing server
            Attributes : - (SMTP server, user name, password)

***Step 3:*** By choosing Advanced settings, we can configure port and certificate options.

And we need to go through the above steps manually,  *but I want to create an Email account programmatically* by using all above settings.

---

***So how can I create new email account from existing Account Services progrmatically?*** I need this functionality for MDM.

Comment: If you found any solutions, Please share. It will help me.

Comment: It seems not possible. You can check about K9. It is an open source project, and you can create any type of email account

Comment: thanks. I haved checked with K9. But it can configure already existing email account. But it is not possible to create(or Register) new email account in K9.

Comment: Yes you are right... You can't do this. Reason is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956050/create-gmail-facebook-and-twitter-account-through-api

Comment: Why don't you reuse the existing account?

Comment: @rds Did you downvoted? First read what is the question, I clearly written I need to programatically create an account for existing Account Services, then what is the confusion?

Comment: @AndroidLearner No. What makes you think so?

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to do this for security reasons.

Imagine accounts being configured with settings that are unknown to the users - the users might not even know the accounts are being created at all! This would be a prime target point for malware, spam etc since no captcha, user permission or any other authentication is involved.

So this is a security measure....and a good one at that.